# how to get count of values from multiple columns

Tags: mysql

i have users_details table with the following columns

```
martial_status | religion | education
```

i want to get count of values from this table as below.

```
married (100)
single (200)
Muslim(50)
Jews (50)
Christian(50)
Graduates(100) 
etc, etc.
```

I do not know if it is possible to get all of the counts using single SELECT , please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
select sum(case when religion = 'Muslim'
           then 1
           else 0 
           end) as muslims,
       sum(case when martial_status = 'married'
           then 1
           else 0 
           end) as married
       ...
from your_table
```

A shorter version of that would be:

```
select sum(religion = 'Muslim') as muslims,
       sum(martial_status = 'married') as married
       ...
from your_table
```

Comment: Thanks i learnt a new syntax of case in mysql. wish you happiness

Comment: Equality results in a boolean result, which is just a 0/1 value in mysql. So sacrificing readability for compactness, you could simply write `sum(religion='Muslim')` and so on.

Comment: @MvG: Good one. Added it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly a single `SELECT`-statement, but you could retrieve it with one query as follows (assuming the columns are compatible):

```
( SELECT `martial_status`, COUNT(*) as `cnt` FROM user_details GROUP BY `martial_status` )
UNION
( SELECT `religion`, COUNT(*) as `cnt` FROM user_details GROUP BY `religion` )
UNION
( SELECT `education `, COUNT(*) as `cnt` FROM user_details GROUP BY `education` )
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to deal with each column seperately and then union it-

```
  SELECT martial_status, count(*)
  FROM USER_DETAILS
  GROUP BY martial_status
UNION ALL
  SELECT religion, count(*)
  FROM USER_DETAILS
  GROUP BY religion
UNION ALL
  SELECT education, count(*)
  FROM USER_DETAILS
  GROUP BY education
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a single `select` with no subqueries or similar is tricky, but I believe that a *single query* should work for you just as well. You can have a single select to obtain all the counts for a given column, and then use `union all` to merge the results so that a single query will get you all the counts of all the columns.

```
select martial_status, count(*) from user_details group by martial_status
union all
select religion, count(*) from user_details group by religion
union all
select education, count(*) from user_details group by education
```

In case you have `NULL` values in your table, you might want to omit those from the results.

If it really is a *single select* which you need, then you would have to alter the layout of your table, but I cannot imagine a valid reason for such a requirement.